# How exactly do electromagnetic fields interact with matter?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

The four equations of Maxwell tell us how electromagnetic fields evolve in time.

Suppose we wanted to describe bulk phenomena... say resistivity for instance, then could we derive them starting from Maxwell's equations?

In this previous stack that I had asked ([here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/582458/how-does-property-of-material-effect-its-interaction-in-faradays-law)), in the comments of the answer by user 'Emmy', one of the users told me that we need "a specific model for the structure of the material concerned"... but what does that mean? Do we need additional constructions on top of Maxwell's equations to model the real world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Dr jh said, Maxwell's equations "are just as fundamental in vacuum as they are anywhere else". But inside a material they can be rewritten in a different way, which is more convenient. I said rewritten, but keep in mind they don't change.

It all starts with the idea that, in a material, there are two kind of sources: free sources and bound sources. The free sources are the ones that can move, for instance the free electrons of a metal. Bound sources are the other ones. These latter bound sources are described by polarization and magnetization vectors, respectively $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{M}$, which are such that:
$$\rho_{\mathrm{bound}}=-\mathrm{div}({\mathbf{P}})
\hspace{10pt}\text{and}\hspace{10pt}
\mathbf{j}_\mathrm{bound}=
\mathrm{\mathbf{rot}}(\mathbf{M})
+\frac{\partial\mathbf{P}}{\partial t}$$

Since only the free sources can be directly controlled in an experiment, the goal is to rewrite Maxwell's equations in such a way that they are the only ones to appear explicitly. To do that, we hide the bound sources into two new fields, the dielectric and magnetic excitations,  respectively $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{H}$, defined by:
$$\mathbf{D} = \varepsilon_0\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{D}
\hspace{10pt}\text{and}\hspace{10pt}
\mathbf{H}=\frac{\mathbf{B}}{\mu_0}-\mathbf{M}$$

By writing $\rho=\rho_{\mathrm{free}}+\rho_{\mathrm{bound}}$ and $\mathbf{j}=\mathbf{j}_{\mathrm{free}}+\mathbf{j}_{\mathrm{bound}}$ in the original Maxwell's equations with sources and after some algebra, one obtains:
$$\mathrm{div}(\mathbf{D})=\rho_{\mathrm{free}}
\hspace{10pt}\text{and}\hspace{10pt}
\mathrm{\mathbf{rot}}(\mathbf{H})=\mathbf{j}_\mathrm{free}+\frac{\partial\mathbf{D}}{\partial t}$$
These two, combined with the two other ones that did not changed in the process, are the Maxwell's equations in matter, also called Maxwell's macroscopic equations. From there, if we want to go further, we need to introduce "a specific model for the structure of the material concerned". That is to say, we have to specify how the bound charges respond to the external fields. The simplest models for this are linear homogeneous isotropic models, in which we have, in complex notation:
$$\underline{\mathbf{P}}(\mathbf{x},t)
= \varepsilon_0\underline{\chi_e}(\omega)
\underline{\mathbf{E}}(\mathbf{x},t)
\hspace{10pt}\text{and}\hspace{10pt}
\underline{\mathbf{M}}(\mathbf{x},t)
= \underline{\chi_m}(\omega)
\underline{\mathbf{H}}(\mathbf{x},t)$$
here, the underlined quantities are complex. The proportionality coefficients $\underline{\chi_e}(\omega)$ and $\underline{\chi_m}(\omega)$ are respectivelity called the dielectric and magnetic susceptibilities. They are characteristics of the material concerned and only depend on the pulsation $\omega$ of the external field $\underline{\mathbf{E}}$, which can be decomposed in Fourier modes without problems because everything is linear in this model. Finally, we make everything really nice by introducing the relatives electric permittivity: $$\underline{\varepsilon_r}(\omega)=(1+\underline{\chi_e}(\omega))$$ and relative magnetic permeability: $$\underline{\mu_r}(\omega)=(1+\underline{\chi_m}(\omega))$$which allows to rewrite Maxwell's equations so that they look like the original ones:
$$\mathrm{div}(\underline{\mathbf{E}})
=\frac{\rho_{\mathrm{free}}}
{\underline{\varepsilon}}
\hspace{10pt}\text{and}\hspace{10pt}
\mathrm{\mathbf{rot}}(\underline{\mathbf{B}})
=\underline{\mu}\mathbf{j}_\mathrm{free}
+\underline{\varepsilon\mu}\frac{\partial\underline{\mathbf{E}}}{\partial t}$$
where $\underline{\varepsilon}=\varepsilon_0\underline{\varepsilon_r}$ and $\underline{\mu}=\mu_0\underline{\mu_r}$. This is I hope all you need to know about Maxwell's equations in matter.

Resistivity, however, is not contained in this discussion. To introduce it, you need to model how the free electrons bounce of the atoms of your material as they are pushed by an external electric field. You can look here for a basic model : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model

Answer (score 2):

The Maxwell Equations are fundamental to nature and applicable to all problems in nature. They are just as fundamental in vacuum as they are anywhere else. As such they do not change or need to be changed if we are using them inside certain materials.

In the case of dielectrics or conductors etc the maxwell equations are modelled accordingly from which we solve simple to the most complex situations.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, maxwell equations are just a 'basis' to speak about electromagnetism they don't really don't model real life directly

Comment: They do. You just add new physical parameters to the original equations depending on what you are studying. The actual equations are fundamental and universal.